# Send custom data types to React Native from Native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-native-module

I'm writing a Native Module for React Native and need to return a value in a custom data type to React Native. To return a value I use the [Promise method](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios.html#promises) like this:

```
// .swift
    
@objc
func getCardType(
  _ cardNumber: NSString,
  resolver resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
  rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock
) {
  let cardType = cardUtils.getTypeOf(cardNumber: String(cardNumber))
  resolve(cardType)
}
```

and expose it to React Native like this:

```
// .m

#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CheckoutBridge, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getCardType:(NSString)cardNumber
  resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject
)

@end
```

The type of `cardType` is `CardType` which is defined by a [3rd party library](https://checkout.github.io/frames-ios/Structs/CardType.html)
When calling the function from React Native, I receive a `null` value, even though I can see the value on the Native side actually being `CardType(scheme: .visa, name: ...)`.

I figured this happens because `cardType` is not one of the supported [argument types](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios.html#argument-types), and realised that it might be possible to use RCTConvert to somehow allow `CardType` values to being sent over the bridge. I had a hard time finding an online reference to how to do this, especially when wanting to do it with Swift. Any Ideas?

Comment: Also had this problem, I resolved by sending standart values like Strings, Ints ets. Maybe u should try this variant.